# Using "to be" with verb "invest"

Tags: grammar

I have encountered the following phrase:
*"Not content with stealing your money for short-term financial gain, cybercriminals are invested in the long-term gain of identity theft".*

Is it a mistake to use "are" here: *"cybercriminals are invested"*?
Shoudn't it be: *"cybercriminals invest"*?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Wiktionary definitions of "[vested](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vested)", "[invested](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/invested)" and "[vested interest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vested_interest#English)". All of them are derived from the same root word "vestis".

A cybercriminal do not invest money, rather he/she invests time, effort and energy. In that sense all these clauses are correct.

> cybercriminals **are investing and will continue to invest** in the long-term gain of identity theft. (It is an ongoing process)

This clause lacks information as to what it is that they are investing ("Are they investing their money?").  This leads to the more informative and **idiomatic** clause below.

> cybercriminals **are investing and will continue to invest their time, effort and energy** in the
> long-term gain of identity theft.

For the sack of brevity, a shorter clause like the ones below may be preferred.

> cybercriminals **have vested interest** in the long-term gain of
> identity theft.
>
> cybercriminals **are invested** in the long-term gain of identity theft.

Edit: **Collins Dictionary** provides this definition for "**invested**".

[Invested](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/17902/invested+%28adj.%29): to be invested in something: to have an interest in something as a result of a commitment to it or an investment in it of resources such as time, effort and money.

- Additional Information: This is an adjective; the word already exists in the dictionary as a verb form.

Apparently this is a new word suggestion, its usage is however already commonplace.

Comment: '... cybercriminals are interested in ...'  would be grammatical. But OP asks about ' ... cybercriminals are invested in ...'. Is _this_ grammatical? According to which authority?

Answer (score 0):

From the meaning of the sentence the sense of the verb can be only the following one.

> (OALD) [transitive] (formal) **to give somebody power or authority, especially as part of their job**
> invest somebody **with** something
>
> - The new position invested her with a good deal of responsibility.

Those people are not money invested in property (sense 1 in the OALD); likewise, the figurative sense 2 is meaningless in this case; as for sense 3, it is evident again, since they are not time, effort or energy spent on something.

It appears that your intuition is verified, and in fact, the use of this particular sense of "to invest", which makes a passive natural, gives in this context more than an incongruous turn to the idea enunciated : it makes it somewhat ironic, since this sense presupposes the action of an authority, the action of giving power to somebody. Moreover, the construction is a perverted one since the preposition one expects, here, is "*with*", not "*in*", and that, in fact, what results is a "cross-meaning" definition.

Logically, this passive makes for nonsense, and the sense that is proper is the third one in OALD.

> [transitive] **to spend time, energy, effort, etc. on something that you think is good or useful**
> **invest something in something**
>
> - She had invested all her adult life in the relationship.
>   **invest something (in) doing something**
> - He had invested so much personal energy turning the company around.
>   invest something Are you willing to invest the time and effort necessary to make the scheme work?

*A possible correct rendering of the idea*

- Not content with stealing your money for short-term financial gain, cybercriminals  invest their energy in the long-term gain of identity theft.